# How to get powershell to read and interpret VS2013 variables (macros)?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, macros

I was looking at some of the macros in VS2013 and noticed that some use what look to be something like powershell syntax calls inside of the registry (less the macros `$(VCTargetsPath)` and `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)`).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0\12.0
    VCTargetsPath    REG_SZ    $([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\'))
```

I tried to execute it, but powershell doesn't seem to understand the type `[MSBuild]`.

How can I interpret this easily, without parsing and translating what it seems to be obviously doing?

## NOTE

My goal is to parse a `.vcxproj` file and extract information from it.  This requires that I evaluate the `Condition` tag attributes, which in turn require that I expand and evaluate them.  If I'm going down the wrong path and you know something about how to do this, then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: *My goal is to parse a .vcxproj file and extract information from it* wich is exactly what msbuild does, by using classes Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project, so instead of spending a lot of time in trying to recreate existing funtionality you're probably better off just using the existing infrastructure. It would help if you explain in more detail what you need when you say the *extract information*.

Comment: @stijn I need to extract the data from the .vcxproj and conditionally move it over to a .props file.

Comment: 'the data' is still rather vague; but did you look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx and other classes in that namespace? They allow extracting all properties/items so it seems they do what you are after..

Comment: @stijn, sorry, pretty new to PowerShell. How do I set this up so that I can access the classes that I need? Maybe I should set up a new question.

Comment: I don't know enough about PS, but I think the easiest way will be to use msbuild or a seperate c# program to extract data and write the props file, then invoke that from PS. Again, if you can post a concrete, minimal example of what you want to do (and yes if you want delete this question and create a new one) then it will be much easier to come up with a solution.